# Pset5 (Speller) Weird Valgrind memory errors, no leaks

Tags: valgrind, cs50

I have read other threads on pset5 Valgrind memory errors, but that didn't help me. I get 0 leaks, but this instead:

**==1917== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
Looks like you're trying to use a variable that might not have a value? Take a closer look at line 34 of dictionary.c.**

The error refers to line 34 which is this:  lower[i] = tolower(word[i]);

To supply context, the code below attempts to check if a word exists in the dictionary that has been uploaded to a hash table. I am attempting to convert the wanted word to lowercase because all the dictionary words are also lowercase and so that their hashes would be identical. The program successfully completes all tasks, but then stumbles upon these memory errors.

Any hints as to why Valgrind is mad at me? Thank you!

```
 // Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char lower[LENGTH + 1]; 

   //Converts word to lower so the hashes of the dictionary entry and searched word would match
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++)
    {
        lower[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }

    // Creates node from the given bucket
    node *tmp = table[hash(lower)];

    // Traverses the linked list
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, tmp->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Below is the whole dictionary.c file:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table 26^3
const unsigned int N = 17576;

// Hash table
node *table[N];
int count = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char lower[LENGTH + 1]; 

   //Converts word to lower so the hashes of the dictionary entry and searched word would match
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++)
    {
        lower[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }

    // Creates node from the given bucket
    node *tmp = table[hash(lower)];

    // Traverses the linked list
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, tmp->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // Modified hash function by Dan Berstein taken from http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html
    unsigned int hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = *word++))
    {
        hash = (((hash << 5) + hash) + c) % N; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }

    return hash;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (dictionary == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s\n.", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    // Create a char array to temporarily hold the new word (r stands for read)
    char r_word[N+1];

    // Until the end of file
    while (fscanf(inptr, "%s", r_word) != EOF)
    {
        // Increments count
        count++;

        // Create a node
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(new_node->word, r_word);

         // Hash the node
        int index = hash(new_node->word);
        // Places the node at the right index
        new_node->next = table[index];
        table[index] = new_node;
    }

    fclose(inptr);

    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (&load == false)
    {
        return '0';
    }
    else
    {
        return count;
    }

}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // Interates over the array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *head = table[i];

        while (head != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you please post the whole file?

Comment: the program is divided into several files that in the end work together, do you mean just the one file that I wrote completely or the whole thing so you could get the functioning of the program?

Comment: can you post your `dictionary.c` here?

Comment: I've just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop iterates through the *maximum length* of `word`-

```c
for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++)
{
    lower[i] = tolower(word[i]);
}
```

Except if you look at how `word` is created-

```c
while (fscanf(inptr, "%s", r_word) != EOF)
{
    // Increments count
    count++;
    // Create a node
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }
    strcpy(new_node->word, r_word);
```

Notice, the variable `r_word`, may not be exactly of length `LENGTH + 1`. So what you really have in `word` is N number of characters, where N is *not necessarily* `LENGTH + 1`, it could be less.

So looping over the entire `0 -> LENGTH + 1` becomes problematic for words that are shorter than `LENGTH + 1`. You're going over array slots that do not have a value, they have garbage values.

What's the solution? This is precisely why c strings have `\0`-

```c
for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    lower[i] = tolower(word[i]);
}
```

This will stop the loop as soon as the NULL character is reached, which, you must have already learnt, marks the end of a string - aka a char array.

There may still be more errors in your code. But for your particular question - reading out of bounds is the answer.

Comment: thanks! This cleared most of the memory problems, but the code still gives 6 errors regarding the while loop of the hash function. I've tried using different hash functions but this still happens. I was wondering if it has to do with the size of my hash table which is pretty arbitrary since I didn't know what to make of it exactly, but then that shouldn't cause issues in the condition, should it?

Comment: Unfortunately a discussion about the hash table is far outside the scope of this question, and you'd also need to be more specific about the errors for anyone to help. I hope my post has answered your specific question though.